# How can I fade a whole html page but not one div?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make the page fade out when I click a button by using the code:

```
$("#post_btn").click(function(){
  $("#address-popup").css({display: "block"});
  $("html,body").fadeTo("slow",0.4);
});
```

The problem is I don't want the div `#address-popup` to fade as well. Is there a way I can exclude this from the `html,body` fade?

Comment: what most people do is slightly different. You would instead add an opaque div that covers the entire page and put the `#address-popup` on top of that div.

Comment: ok how could i add a div that covers the whole page? or whats the best way to overlay a div in the way i want and fade all the background? without using a plug-in im trying to learn code and using a plug in is too boring

Comment: Google for a tutorial on creating modal dialogs in jQuery.

Comment: solved it thanks everyone for pointing me the right way :)

Comment: I have now added an overlay div but how do i add my box on top oif the overlay so it doesnt look faded out?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. You can't fade the entire document but not some elements within the document.

You're going about this the wrong way. Popups which appear to dim the background typically append a semi-transparent overlay div, which the dialog sits on top of. It is the overlay div which partially obscures the page; the page itself doesn't actually fade out.

Comment: I'll add that these are usually called "modal popups" or "modal dialogs" and many libraries (including jQuery UI) already have implementations made. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: I have now added an overlay div but how do i add my box on top oif the overlay so it doesnt look faded out? –

Comment: Your dialog needs to be a sister element to the overlay, it cannot be contained within it. Style it with a higher z-index than the overlay div.

Comment: i have styled it with a higher z-index but still isnt working what is a sister element?

Comment: sister element === sibling element. Same depth in DOM tree and same parent. The easiest way to do this is to just make them both children of the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a visible child of a hidden parent.
What you need is to append your popup to your body element, and then fade out all of the other elements inside body.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <div class="header">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
   </div>
   <div class="popup">
   </div>
</body
```

**JS:**

```
$("#post_btn").click(function(){
   $("body > div:not(.popup)").fadeTo("slow",0.4);
});
```

Comment: Typo, meant to add > (direct child). fixed now

Comment: This is grossly simplified and hardly practical for real-world pages, but it does technically answer the question. It's a case of the person asking the question not really knowing what's best for them however. Using an overlay div is definitely a better solution.

Comment: thanks i have done it with a overlay div :) i am new to creating interactive content haha

Answer (score 1):

I'm tested a solution here and it worked...

```
$("#post_btn").click(function(){
  $("body :not(#address-popup)").fadeTo("slow",0.4);
});
```

It worked very well...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off creating the "illusion" of a fading background by overlaying a `<div>` and giving it transparency. Give this `<div>` a `z-index` higher than the rest of the page's content.

Then, to greate the illusion of your other `#address-popup` div sitting above the faded page, just make sure it has an even higher `z-indez` than the transparent `<div>`.

Comment: I have now added an overlay div but how do i add my box on top oif the overlay so it doesnt look faded out? –

Comment: Use the `z-index` CSS property to set it to a higher number than the overlay. The overlay should be higher than everything it overlays, except the `#address-popup` div.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="blind"></div>
<div class="topDiv">
<h1>Popup Effect DIV</h1>
<p>This DIV will still display when the rest of the page has been faded out</p>
</div>
<a class="fadeOut">Load Popup.</a>
```

CSS

```
.blind {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha( opacity = 90 );
    display: none;
}
.topDiv {
    display: none;
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 2000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

JS

```
/* Load Popup and fade background */
$('.fadeOut').click(function(e){
    $('.blind').toggle();
    $('.topDiv').toggle();
});
/* Close popup and loose fade when you click outside the popup */
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $('.topDiv');
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
        $('.blind').hide();
    }
});
```